# TextView Marquee not working even after calling TextView.setSelected(true)

Tags: android, textview, marquee

for my case, the marquee still doesn't work even after i had tried several solutions provided in stackoverflow.

here is my xml content:
    ...

```
           .... // XML for Other Views here

            <TextView android:id="@+id/progress"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:singleLine="true"
                  android:ellipsize="marquee"
                  android:focusable="true"
                  android:clickable="true"
                  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                  android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                  android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_weight="2"
                  />
    </LinearLayout>
```

...

every needed(or maybe needed) attributes is set, right?

below is the way i use the TextView in my code:

1) this TextView is one component of an fragment.

2) this component is inited in Fragment's call back function : `onAcitvityCreated()` in the way below:

```
m_progressView = (TextView) m_activity.findViewById(R.id.progress);
```

Note : m_activity is the activity the fragment belong to.

3) then calling `setSelected(true)` after `setText()` as below:

```
            m_activity.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                public void run()
                {
                    m_progressView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);

                    m_progressView.setText(new String("第" + g_currentPage + "页    共" + g_totalPages + "页"));

                    m_progressView.setSelected(true);


                }
            }, 500);
```

but it doesn't work.

while i open eclipse's logcat，i get cyclic logs like :

```
07-28 19:30:31.639: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer]     this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.93, dur:1038.04, max:549.31, min:488.73

07-28 19:30:32.645: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.99, dur:1006.23, max:507.58, min:498.65

07-28 19:30:33.661: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.97, dur:1015.59, max:512.58, min:503.00

07-28 19:30:34.716: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.90, dur:1054.77, max:543.55, min:511.22

07-28 19:30:36.230: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.98, dur:1514.01, max:534.81, min:460.85

07-28 19:30:37.733: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:2.00, dur:1502.85, max:507.72, min:493.80

07-28 19:30:38.761: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.94, dur:1028.36, max:535.38, min:492.98

07-28 19:30:39.771: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.98, dur:1009.94, max:506.94, min:503.01

07-28 19:30:40.772: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:2.00, dur:1000.87, max:514.48, min:486.39

07-28 19:30:41.815: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.92, dur:1043.46, max:531.82, min:511.64

07-28 19:30:42.860: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.91, dur:1044.70, max:543.25, min:501.45

07-28 19:30:44.357: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:2.00, dur:1496.71, max:508.20, min:481.11

07-28 19:30:45.381: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.95, dur:1024.39, max:531.66, min:492.74

07-28 19:30:46.420: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:2.89, dur:1039.11, max:511.83, min:66.67

07-28 19:30:47.476: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.89, dur:1056.07, max:531.04, min:525.03

07-28 19:30:48.481: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.99, dur:1004.86, max:511.82, min:493.04

07-28 19:30:49.493: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.98, dur:1011.62, max:533.93, min:477.69

07-28 19:30:50.530: I/SurfaceTextureClient(20944): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5a8be558) fps:1.93, dur:1037.57, max:563.91, min:473.67
```

it seems that the marquee mechanism is working according these logs, but why the text doesn't move?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fact"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more">

    <requestFocus
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</TextView>
```